# Trying to map response in table but not getting expected output

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, user-interface, frontend

```
function App() {
  let response = [
    {
      id: 134,
      user_name: 'abc',
      phone_number: 1234567890,
      children: [
        { id: 46, user_name: 'Sid', phone_number: 9834763467 },
        { id: 50, user_name: 'Tom', phone_number: 9834763467 },
      ],
    },
    {
      id: 948,
      user_name: 'def',
      phone_number: 9823437483,
      children: [
        { id: 20, user_name: 'Lina', phone_number: 9834763467 },
      ],
    },
    {
      id: 865,
      user_name: 'abc',
      phone_number: 1234567890,
      children: [
        { id: 60, user_name: 'Nikk', phone_number: 9834763467 },
        { id: 15, user_name: 'Mina', phone_number: 9834763467 },
      ],
    },
  ];

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Id</th>
            <th>name</th>
            <th>child name</th>
            <th>child id</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {response.map((value, index) => {
            return (
              <>
                <tr key={value.id}>
                  <td rowSpan={value['children'].length}>{value["id"]} 
                 </td>
                  <td rowSpan={value['children'].length}> 
                 {value["user_name"]}</td>
                  <td>{value["children"].map((child) => {
                    return (
                      <td>{child.user_name}</td>
                    );
                  })}</td>
                  <td>{value["children"].map((child) => {
                    return (
                      <td>{child.id}</td>
                    );
                  })}</td>
                </tr>
              </>
            );
          })}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**As I am trying to add rowspan attribute in table cell it only showing two rows only and third name showing in other column as well getting problem in mapping children name. the expected output will be 2 rowspan for first id of object and 1 rowspan for second id of object and 2 rowspan for second id of object and same for user_name. Expected table attached below**
[image]

Comment: It looks like you have a syntax error when mapping the `children`. You're directly closing your map function `map((data))`

Comment: thanks for correction @RubenSmn but still not getting the output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I couldn't comment so I am adding an answer here with a potential solution.

So I found that you have a typo of sorts, you didn't write your second map function correctly, this is how it should be:

```
<td>
   {value['children'].map((data, index) => {
     return <td key={index}>{data['user_name']}</td>;
   })}
</td>
```

I hope this helps, in case it's not helpful, please provide a screenshot or something of what you're seeing and maybe explain with a sketch what you want to do as well, I'll do my best to help you out!

Edit:
According to your sketch I think this should work, the trick is to lay out the first element of the children array first with the other data, and then use slice to remove the first element and loop through the rest to add them to the table.

```
 <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Id</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Phone number</th>
        <th>Child id</th>
        <th>Child name</th>
        <th>Child phone number</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      {response.map((value, index) => {
        return (
          <React.Fragment key={value.id}>
            <tr>
              <td rowSpan={value['children'].length}>{value['id']}</td>
              <td rowSpan={value['children'].length}>
                {value['user_name']}
              </td>
              <td rowSpan={value['children'].length}>
                {value['phone_number']}
              </td>
              <td>{value['children'][0]['id']}</td>
              <td>{value['children'][0]['user_name']}</td>
              <td>{value['children'][0]['phone_number']}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              {value['children'].slice(1).map((data, index) => {
                return <React.Fragment key={index}> 
                  <td>{data['id']}</td>
                  <td>{data['user_name']}</td>
                  <td>{data['phone_number']}</td>
                </React.Fragment>;
              })}
            </tr>
            /*
            <tr>
              You can add a row here at the end if you want to add what
              you mentioned.
            </tr>
            */
          </React.Fragment>
        );
      })}
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

You should also make sure that the data you received does have children, for example by checking the length before starting to display your data, just as a safety measure.

This is how it looks:
[image]

This is a link to [playcode](https://playcode.io/1292682) to check the code live.

Comment: I have attached image as well

Comment: Okay let me check

Comment: @devReact Hello I updated my answer yesterday let me know if this works for you or if you have questions

Comment: It's working fine but the problem is mapping children array. Suppose if we have different user_name in each children array - @Mirou

Comment: I have updated the question. can you can please look into it.

Comment: I will do that and see how to update the answer

Comment: I tried but I have to loop again in children array. Is it right way?

<td rowSpan={value['children'].length}> 
                 {value["user_name"]}</td>
                  <td>{value["children"].map((child) => {
                    return (
                      <td>{child.user_name}</td>
                    );
                  })}</td>
                  <td>{value["children"].map((child) => {
                    return (
                      <td>{child.id}</td>
                    );
                  })}</td>

Comment: Let me test it and get back to you

Comment: @devReact I edited my solution check please

Comment: the trick here is if you use React.Fragment you don't have to make several loops you can just put any data you want inside it

Comment: Don't forget to accept my answer please if this is what you're looking for! It'll be helpful for me and for people who stumble upon this.

Comment: I didn't get your question tbh, but what I did there is that inside the first <tr> you have to put everything first before looping the rest of the data, and that's why I used value['children'][0], if you have more data inside children you can just add another td next to them and call that data then do the same with the loop at the end

Comment: Understood! I have one more question related to this. If I have to add all the Ids(number) and show below the table

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252478/discussion-between-mirou-and-devreact).

Answer (score 1):

If you take a look in your console you'll probably find something like

```js
Warning: validateDOMNesting(...): <td> cannot appear as a child of <td>.
```

Since a `td` element can not appear as a child of a `td` element you could try the following.

```js
{
  response.map((value, index) => {
    return (
      <tr key={value.id}>
        <td>{value["id"]}</td>
        <td>{value["user_name"]}</td>
        <td>{value["children"].map((child) => child.user_name).join(",")}</td>
      </tr>
    );
  });
}
```

This will result in a column with all the names of the children listed separated by comma's.

Or you could create dedicated rows for your children below the parent like so:

```js
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Id</th>
      <th>Name</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    {response.map((value, index) => {
      return (
        <>
          <tr key={value.id}>
            <td>{value["id"]}</td>
            <td>{value["user_name"]}</td>
          </tr>
          {value["children"].map((child) => {
            return (
              <tr style={{ background: "yellow" }}>
                <td>{child.id}</td>
                <td>{child.user_name}</td>
              </tr>
            );
          })}
        </>
      );
    })}
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks but I am getting problem while using rowSpan as it's the number of objects of children array

Comment: I have updated the question. can you can please look into it.